What is the difference between the definititons of big O?
I have seen different types of big O notations.
$$
f(n)\le C g(n) \quad \forall n\ge n_{0}\\
|f(n)|\le C g(n) \quad \forall n\ge n_{0} \\
|f(n)|\le C |g(n)| \quad \forall n\ge n_{0} \\
$$
Also n can be in different sets of numbers (integer or a natural number). I was wondering why there are differences between them and which one is better depending on use.

Note that $f$ or $g$ taking negative values can break the less "absolute value-y" versions.  If one is using Big-O to measure size, then we should also only be interested in the sizes (absolute values) of $f$ and $g$.  You don't actually specify a use case, so it's not clear whether this applies to your Question.
